# PHP array rename keys

Tags: php

I have an array like this, the keys are epoch timestamps they were used to order the files by date i now want to rename the keys to 0, 1, 2, 3, etc

```
Array($files)
(
    [1365168386] => _MG_5704.jpg
    [1368201277] => _MG_5702.jpg
    [1368201719] => jetty.jpg
    [1368202375] => _MG_6100.jpg
    [1368202758] => _MG_5823.jpg
    [1368203032] => _MG_5999.jpg
    [1368203244] => _MG_5794.jpg
    [1368203477] => _MG_5862.jpg
    [1368203727] => _MG_6028.jpg
)
```

so it becomes

```
Array($files)
(
    [0] => _MG_5704.jpg
    [1] => _MG_5702.jpg
    [2] => jetty.jpg
    [3] => _MG_6100.jpg
    [4] => _MG_5823.jpg
    [5] => _MG_5999.jpg
    [6] => _MG_5794.jpg
    [7] => _MG_5862.jpg
    [8] => _MG_6028.jpg
)
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: You want to hear about [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Answer (score 6):

array_values returns a numeric array, starting from 0: http://php.net/array_values

```
$files = array_values($files);
```

array_values also maintains the order.

Comment: Thanks, i'd done it using a loop but knew there was a function that would do it in one go but just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = array_map('array_values', $files);
```

This will reset all your key values in your array.

Comment: what? array_values on the string values of the array?

Comment: @bwoebi correct me if I am wrong, it is late here haha, but the 'array_values' part is a callback function and will be applied to each array element in $files?

Comment: array_values expects an array as parameter, not the values of the array. But array_map passes the values of each entry to array_values. Try it yourself...

Comment: @bwoebi  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array is what I was getting